# Manage permissions on library subfolder SharePoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, item-level-permissions, sharepoint-permissions

I'm using SharePoint form Microsoft 365

I have created site and added some members. I created a library on it, but I would like that only some persons have access to certain subfolders inside (not all site members). I have read about breaking inheritance, and granting excusive permissions on folders, but, as far as I can see, on 365 I can only do it at library level, not subfolder or item level.

Is there a way to perform this on 365, or using different libraries is the better (or even unique) approach to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break permissions inheritance and grant excusive permissions on folders as well in SharePoint online.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to document library
2. Click on ellipsis (`...`) - three dots next to folder name & select **Manage access**

   [image]
3. It will open a panel at right side of screen. Scroll to the bottom of panel & click on **Advanced** link

   [image]
4. It will open permissions page for that particular folder where you can break permissions & grant permissions to users/groups

   [image]

---

Also, if you are going to have fix set of subfolders (not going to increase in future) & there are only few subfolders, you can manage this using different libraries as well. Permissions management will be easier using this approach than creating subfolders inside only one library.

Comment: Can't belive I didn't see it! :( Thanks!